# git://github.com/odorcicd/authlogic.git (at rails3) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic

I am getting an error:--

```
 git://github.com/odorcicd/authlogic.git (at rails3) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install`
```

Even after running bundle install. I tried this but still no luck

```
cd vendor/plugins
git clone git://github.com/odorcicd/authlogic.git
cd authlogic
git checkout --track -b rails3 origin/rails3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:-

Relace

```
gem 'authlogic', :git => 'git://github.com/odorcicd/authlogic.git', :branch => 'rails3'
```

by

```
gem 'authlogic'
```

Make sure you do:--

```
  cd vendor/plugins
  git clone git://github.com/odorcicd/authlogic.git
  cd authlogic
  git checkout --track -b rails3 origin/rails3
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to clone the gem repos locally prior to running bundle install. It should just work with the remote git repos.

I've spent a week trying everything to figure an issue out like this. Following ALL of the troubleshooting steps here finally resolved it:

https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/master/ISSUES.md

Good luck!